# Checking if the .bak file is corrupt

Tags: sql-server

Actually I am getting below error while executing command like

```
RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM DISK='F:\dbNewsPaper201707051200.BAK'
```

> Msg 3203, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>    Read on "F:\dbNewsPaper201707051200.BAK" failed: 38(Reached the end of the file.)
>    Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>    VERIFY DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Comment: Was there any changes done to DB server since the back up was done? See link where DWORD change in registry caused this https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/41428/restore-verifyonly-verify-database-is-terminating.html

Comment: No changes done to DB server.